# Windows 8 - Installed app missing once I close the emulator and reopened?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I started working on windows-8 this morning and I am surprised that installed app not displayed in the emulator which I installed in the morning. To be clear.
1. I created the new project called `Test1` using visual studio Express 2012.
2. I installed on the emulator.
3. I close the emulator completely.
4. After an hour I created `Test2` using visual studio Express 2012.

But i am not able to find the `Test1` project in windows-8 phone emulator.

But when i work on iPhone and android the apps will be available if i recreate the emulator.

What could be wrong?. Do I need to change any settings?

Comment: Are you talking about Windows 8 apps or Windows Phone 8? Are you actually running Visual Studio on Windows 8 too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the emulator does not persist app installs to the base image. (this was true with WP7x emulators). I don't remember seeing anything that tells me it has changed.

Emulator shutdown + start == fresh new emulator. Only time it persists your app etc is when you change settings like display language etc and emulator initiates a restart.